IntelliJ Idea setting incorrect kotlin package name on new or moved files
In IntelliJ, whenever I create a new Kotlin file, or whenever I move a file from one package to another, it is populating the incorrect package in the first line of the file.
For example: I have a file in com.myservice.config, correctly labeled
package com.myservice.config
If I move that class to another package, say com.myservice.config.properties, or if I simply create a new class file in that package, IntelliJ sets the package to
package com.myservice.com.myservice.config.properties
Interestingly, IntelliJ's static code analysis does not seem to recognize that this package is incorrect. If I correct the package to what it should be, then it is also happy. However, if I intentionally put some nonsense into the pacakge name, say, appending ".foo" to the end of the package then it is highlighted as a problem.
I'm currently running IntelliJ IDEA 2024.2.4 (Ultimate Edition) but this issue has been present for quite a while. I haven't figured out how to even phrase my search terms to get an answer from google despite several attempts over the last couple of years this has been happening. It's a subtle issue that has made it into my master branch quite a few different times and I keep having to correct it when I find it.
Is there some setting I'm missing that is overriding the default package setting?
Edit/Update:
I submitted a bug report to jetbrains but I'm not able to create a MRE for them as it seems to only happen in my one project.
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/7020481

This may be a bug in IntelliJ - Have you tried filing a report with JetBrains?

I have not. I figured the first thing I should do is make sure there's not some setting I was missing

I just submitted the report. We'll see what they say

@StormeHawke could you please add the link to the issue you created, in case other people have the same problem?

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/7020481
